# Issue with view being rotated even if I return NO on shouldAutorotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController  and I have this code there :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return NO;

}
```

However, if I change the orientation, the view rotates. Can anyone kindly help me out ?

Comment: Try making it return YES if it is your supported orientation (you need at least 1 right?).  Depending on the implementation of UIViewController (or code that uses this method to determine rotations), this may or may not help your problem, but would be more correct.

Comment: @Matt : I have tried it that way too... doesnt work :(

Comment: Same issue with me, what solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it to keep an iPad in landscape mode:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    return YES;
}

else
{
    return NO;
}

}
```

Comment: I have something similar too. It still rotates :( ... The view controller is inside a navigation controller with more view controllers beneath it. Do you think that might cause a problem ?

Comment: yes, are you putting the code in the mainViewcontroller??? if that doesn't work, look up how to specify it in the plist for your app.

Comment: noope, its not in the root view controller.my code is another view controller that I push into the nav controller stack.

Comment: the plist should allow all rotation. Only on this specific view controller, it should be Landscape (left/right) only.